# Load method in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to alert massage when div having id b is loaded.

```
<div id='a'>a</div>
<div id='b'>b</div>
<div id='c'>c</div>


$(function(){
$('#b').load(function(){
alert(0)
})
})
```

Comment: I'm afraid that load event doesn't apply to div elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748084/jquery-attach-function-to-load-event-of-an-element

Answer (score 1):

Load event doesn't apply to div elements. 
As far as I'm aware the best you can do is

```
<div id='a'>a</div>
<div id='b'>b</div>

<script>
   alert(0);
</script>

<div id='c'>c</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply the event load or ready to a div elements.
You could use this code, that alert when all DOM is ready or loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("0");
});
```

or

```
$(window).load(function() {
   alert("0");
});
```

Comment: This will load when dom is loaded. But i want to alert before div id 'c' is loaed